# RStudio (0.99.473) on Win 7 64-bit SP1 -- Empty Parent Window on Startup, Nothing Works

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to run RStudio 0.99.473 on my Windows 7 64-bit SP1 machine.  Everything was going well until I attempted an unsuccessful plot command.  After that point, I have not been able to produce a plot in RStudio.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both RStudio and R (version 3.2.2) several times.  I have been doing several searches for a couple hours now and have had no luck.  I have navigated to `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop`, but deleted the `RStudio-Desktop` folder before I thought about or saw any advice to just re-name it.  I've attempted to navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\RStudio-Desktop` but apparently I am unable to access it.

Now when I try to run RStudio, even after performing a fresh install, I get this terrible empty parent window with only the words in the menu bar.  Clicking on the menu words produces nothing.  Basically, all the usual advice that I've seen in my searches is not working.  Nothing seems to reset the settings back to the default.

Comment: OK, looks like this has somehow been resolved.  Maybe I just needed to be patient and wait a bit.  Who knows.  At any rate my installation is now working.  The question now has turned to "I cannot plot anything, because I get this error: `Error in par(mar = c(2, 2, 3, 3,)) : no active or default device`.  I have been searching quite a while for a solution to this, but it seems I cannot find one.  Anyone have any thoughts?  No matter what I do I can't get a plot to show up in the Plots pane.  If I just try to `plot(1:10,1:10)` I get `error in dev.hold() : no active or default device`.

Comment: After closing the interactive plotting device (which is usually started automagically, even by naked R sessions), you can try `plot.new()` to re-initialize it.

Comment: When I tried `plot.new()` to re-initialize, I got the same error: `Error in plot.new() : no active or default device`.  I'm also noticing that my Environment seems to have disappeared.  There is no auto-complete suggestions, and the function `qqnorm()` was not found.

Comment: I'm worried your installation is corrupted. `options("device")` should return a function that starts up the default screen device. What's it return?

Comment: @BondedDust: `options("device")` returns `"RStudioGD"`.  I thought maybe the issue had resolved magically over the weekend, as I came in, tried a plot, and it worked.  But then I tried to do one of my boxplots and I got the "no active or default device" message again.  I also keep getting the message `R symbol not found` when I type in a command.  Most of the time it works anyway, but I found one or two last week that did not.  I don't recall what they were now.

Comment: Well, "RStudioGD" is not a function, but the value for that option can be the name of a function. You should be able to examine that function.

Comment: OK, well thanks.  I'm just really confused as to how I can get my installation uncorrupted and working properly again.  I didn't realize how much I take RStudio for granted until I have to use the basic R console alone.

Comment: You might try some of the RStudio specific advice in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292563/how-do-i-reset-the-graphical-parameters-back-to-default-values-without-use-of-de . I don't know if RStudio saves its exit state in a hidden `.RData` file, but regular R does and you night try tracking it down and renaming it to see if a restart lets things proceed more pleasantly. You should be able to find SO or SU answers about how to make Windoze display hidden files.

Comment: OK, thanks so much!  I have no problem making Win display hidden files - that part's easy.  I'll take a look at the linked answers and see what that gets me.  FWIW I did try searching substantially prior to attempting to post on this.  I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: The possibility of corrupted `.RData` files causing weird startup weirdness (even crashes)  is something that I learned on the Rhelp mailing list.