# How to fix legend's margins in base::plot?

Tags: r, plot

I tried to reproduce the plot from akrun's answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509743/legends-not-showing-up-in-r-plots/69509762):

```
#create data
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

#making plot
plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1", 
      ylim = c(0, 100))
legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
      col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

What had @akrun:
[image]

What have I (legend has another form and parameters):

[image]

What can be the problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue; I am taking a plot similar to the first one (R 4.1.0 on Ubuntu)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue.  It is still giving me the same output as the first one.  Maybe check your `options()` .  I am using R 4.1.1 on a mac

Comment: @desertnaut i don't know, where is a problem. But when i reproduce (f.e.) an plot from Kabakoff's book ```Figure 3.10 An annotated comparison of Drug A and Drug B``` p.62 - i have the same problem.

Comment: @akrun what i should check?  i have 4.1.0. on Windows

Comment: @manro Can you type in `par()` on your console and it gives all the default parameter values.  Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292563/reset-the-graphical-parameters-back-to-default-values-without-use-of-dev-off)

Comment: @akrun np - i do it. corrected the question

Comment: Main reason is I can't reopen somebody closed question because of a meta post

Comment: This is reopened now. I rolled back the answer section because your question should remain strictly a question. It's still available from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69404370/revisions) if you want to post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `windows()` command saves the day; in the *pop-out window*, the legend looks OK:

```
#create data
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

windows() #!!!!HERE

#making plot
plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1", 
   ylim = c(0, 100))
legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
   col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

[image]