# Legends not Showing up in R plots

Tags: r, plot, graph, data-visualization

I am working with R. I made the following plots:

```
#create data
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 2
d = data.frame(a,b,i)
d$col = as.factor(ifelse(d$a>10,"red", "blue"))

a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 3
e = data.frame(a,b,i)
e$col = as.factor(ifelse(e$b>10,"red", "blue"))




#create data
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

plot_1 = plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1")



plot_2 = plot(d$a, type = "h", col = d$col, main = "plot_2, i = 2")



plot_3 = plot(e$a, type = "h", col = e$col, main = "plot_3, i = 3")
```

[image]

I am trying to add legends to all of these plots:

```
plot_1 = plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1")


legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)

plot_2 = plot(d$a, type = "h", col = d$col, main = "plot_2, i = 2")

legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)

plot_3 = plot(e$a, type = "h", col = e$col, main = "plot_3, i = 3")

legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

But none of these legends are showing up. Does anyone know why these legends are not working? I know how to do this in ggplot, but it is not working with the base plots in R. I am following the instructions from this website here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-legends-to-plots-in-r-software-the-easiest-way. Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is an option: `legend("topleft", legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `legend` location is outside the `ylim` i.e. by default, the `ylim` is calculated based on the `min/max` values, change the `ylim` and it appears.  i.e. currently the `ylim` is at 0, 35, whereas the location specified for y axis is 95 (huge difference)

```
plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1", 
      ylim = c(0, 100))
legend(1, 95, legend=c("Sampled", "Not Sampled"),
        col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Can i ask you in "next answer" of this post? I can't create a new question because system says that: "You have reached your question limit"? It consdiers a legend too.

Comment: @ manro: what do you mean?